# Angular Bootstrap is creating duplicate bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple modal that appears when the user enters a page, but it is creating two of them. I have looked through the app and there are not two calls to the modal.

Here is the controller for it:

```
 angular.module('rokoApp')
    .controller('FinanceCtrl', function($scope, $modal) {

     $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'includes/modal.html',
          controller: function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $modal,$modalInstance){
          console.log('opened')
          $scope.cancel = function () {
             $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          };

      }
 });
```

Comment: Are you using ui-route or ngRoute? If so, how do they look like?

Comment: ngRoute:  `.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .when('/financial', {
        templateUrl: 'views/financial.html',
        controller: 'FinanceCtrl'
      })`

Comment: There's a syntax error in your snippet. Is this the exact code your using?

Comment: no it was just an example of the route provider. all the other routes follow the same logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will be much better if you give us an example of functional code in plunker or jsfiddle, because the problem could be in another place.

For example:

When we started creating an app with AngularJS usually we put `ng-controller` in a upper tag and write the first lines of our app. The problem is that some times when we added routing we forget remove the `ng-controller` and then the controller is executing twice. The first time with the configuration of the module and again with the processing of the html.
So the solution here is to remove the tag in the html if we use routing or delete the controller property of routing and keep the `ng-controller` in the html.

I will let you the two codes:

With the error: http://plnkr.co/edit/TmQ5QhjD55WTurQNaEIv

Without the error: http://plnkr.co/edit/1xGUGEvAZ6jUBs8CbhTT